Is there a rule to find $\gcd(a^m,b^n)$?
Given positive integers $a$, $b$, $m$, $n$, find $\gcd(a^m,b^n)$.
I don't know how to approach the case with powers having different bases and exponents.
However, I know that:

$\gcd(a^m,a^n)=a^{\min(m,n)}$ (pick the smallest exponent).
$\gcd(a^m,b^m)=\gcd(a,b)^m$ (greatest common divisor of bases taken m times by how gcd is obtained out of prime factors)

I've been trying to reduce this problem to the case I know by assuming without loss of generality that $m < n$, and doing the following:
$\gcd(a^m,b^n)=\gcd(a^m,b^m\cdot b^{n-m})$.
Edit: For the prime decomposition, if we take $a = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_u^{\alpha_u}$ and $b = q_1^{\beta_1}q_2^{\beta_2}\cdots q_v^{\beta_v}$, then $a^m = p_1^{m\alpha_1}p_2^{m\alpha_2}\cdots p_u^{m\alpha_u}$ and $b^n = q_1^{n\beta_1}q_2^{n\beta_2}\cdots q_v^{n\beta_v}$.
How do I proceed?

Hello, I suggest you write the decomposition into prime numbers of $a$ and $b$ and deduce something about the gcd you are looking for.

I don't think you can write $\min(m \alpha, n \beta)$ as a function of just $\min( \alpha, \beta)$. Here $ \alpha$ and  $\beta$ are exponents in the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$.

If $(a,b)=1$, then $(a^m,b^n)=1$.
If $(a,b)=r_1^{c_1} \ldots r_k^{c_k}$ where $r_i^{c_i} = p_u^{\min{\{\alpha_u,\beta_v\}}} = q_v^{\min{\{\alpha_u,\beta_v\}}}$ and $r_i$ are all distinct, then $(a^m,b^n) = r_1^{\min\{m\alpha_1,n\beta_1\}} \times r_2^{\min\{m\alpha_2,n\beta_2\}}\times \ldots \times r_k^{\min\{m\alpha_k,n\beta_k\}}$
It is just the method how hand calculation works. For example, let $a=2^3 3^6 5^7 7$ and $b=2^23^45^9 11$ where $m,n$ are both positive integers, then $(a,b)=2^2 3^4 5^7$. Then $(a^m,b^n) = 2^{\min\{3m,2n\}} \times 3^{\min\{6m,4n\}} \times 5^{\min\{7m,9n\}}$

If you are given a and b already, then it just directly calculate it. If a and b are not be given, then you need to proceed an algorithm to find it. You will get the answer for sure.
